# Convert today's HH:MM am/pm to epoch in Bash

Tags: bash, date, time, epoch

I have two variables `$sunrise`="7:23 am" and `$sunset`="6:10 pm". I need to convert both of them to today's epoch equivalent as in:

```
secSunrise=($date ... "$sunrise" ... +"%s")
secSunset=$(date ... "$sunset" ... +"%s")
```

The only thing I've figured out so far is doing it with current date-time:

```
$ secNow=$(date +"%s")
$ echo $secNow
1488331535
```

How to square this circle and plug the `HH:MM am/pm` 12-hour formatted variable into the `date` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use GNU `date` this way:

```
date --date="7:23 am today" +%s
# output => 1488352980

date --date="6:10 pm today" +%s
# output => 1488391800
```

- `%s` prints epoch

---

From `man date`:

> The  `--date=STRING`  is a mostly free format human readable date string
>   such as `"Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800"` or `"2004-02-29 16:21:42"` or
>   even `"next Thursday"`.  A date string may contain items indicating
>   calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time,
>   relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning
>   of the day.  The date string format is more complex than is easily
>   documented here but is fully described in the info documentation.

Comment: `--date` is a fantastic feature. Tested and `secSunrise=$(date --date="$sunrise today" +%s)` works fine.